Emacs LSP autocompleting functions with weird argument placeholders
I'm setting up my Emacs config on the go while doing some uni projects and now after setting up lsp-mode with ccls I have this problem where function completions always come with placeholders for arguments.
For example a function defined as:
void foo(int a, String * str);
Will be autocompleted to:
foo($:{1:int a}, ${2:String *str})
I would like to either make the placeholders be the type of variable or get rid of them so I don't have to manually delete every time.

This is yas-snippet placeholders, you should enable yas-global-mode, as it discribed in installation section
(yas-global-mode 1)

